# Oracle SELECT <var name> AS <column name> equivalent after stored procedure where <var name> is an outbound parameter (JDBC/SQL Only no SQL*Plus)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, parameters

**Does Oracle have a way other than using using `DBMS_OUTPUT` to render the content of returned variables coming back out of a stored procedure via `SELECT`?**

I'm aware of functions too, but I don't have a say in rewriting things, in case that's what people are thinking of responding with.

```
DECLARE
NAME TIDAL.JOBMST.JOBMST_NAME%TYPE; -- Oracle syntax to base the type of variable upon a column in a table. It resolves to varchar2(256) 
BEGIN
TIDAL.GETJOBNAMEFORID(1,NAME); -- 'NAME' is an outbound parameter of stored procedure and gets bound to variable 'NAME' in DECLARE above.
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name: ' || NAME); -- || is Oracle string concat `+` anywhere else!
END;
```

---

The program that processes this SQL via JDBC needs to be able to render output as a CSV, XML or raw payload. It can only do all these options with the "`select`" style output. (probably using Java's Resultset API)

The `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE` doesn't generate output within the program that processes the SQL. DBeaver does. So this doesn't work for me either.

---

**I thought there would be some awkward `SELECT :NAME FROM DUAL` or `SELECT NAME: = NAME INTO DUAL` syntax I could use to render it, since Oracle won't allow a `SELECT` without a `FROM` akin to SQL Server (see below), but the solution eludes me.**

In this case the result is a scalar, but it could equally be one or more records, or rows of a single column..
I would like to use `AS` in order to be able to label the column(s) for a downstream processes too.

**Can someone tell me if this is possible?**

The code has to pass JDBC SQL parser syntax checks and generates no ORA error code. The bulk of the solutions I see on Oracle on the internet seem flaky. SQL*Plus answers with things like `var` or `exec` or `print` don't seem to work with JDBC SQL. I've been trying to validate things via DBeaver too - and most of the time a colon prepends variable names it seems to prompt for input so I'm not sure if that/my Oracle knowledge, is muddying the waters and I should try SQL Developer to validate code instead.

---

This would be the equivalent in SQL Server of what I want to achieve in Oracle:

```
DECLARE 
@NAME varchar(256),
EXEC GETJOBNAMEFORID
     1
     @NAME = @NAME OUTPUT;
SELECT @NAME As Name
```

---

Other that this canned example I don't have visibility to the stored procedures to know if a `sys_refcursor` is in use on outbound parameters either.

Comment: SQL is not responsible for display, it even have no any embedded tool to display anything. It is a language that processes the data and returns a resultset (or some variables with data in case of PL/SQL). Data display is a task for the frontend. DBeaver, SQL Developer, SSMS or SQLPlus are *tools* that do processing of *the result* of SQL statements. How to receive the output of `dbms_output` depends on the language you use at the frontend.

Comment: @astentx - that's not what I am saying. The program that processes the SQL is smart enough to be able to interpret the results and re-render it in things like CSV or XML. But it has to be something similar to the way SQL Server does it. I daresay via https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Comment: It is not clear what you try to achieve. You've posted some T-SQL code that returns a result set with a single row and single column named `name`. Of course you may also do the same with Oracle's SQL: just run SQL statement. If you want to return result set from PL/SQL the things get complicated, since Oracle doesn't return anything from PL/SQL block. Is the latter what you need? Then you need to use `sys_refcursor` variables and process them or use pipelined function and select `from` it. In short: you cannot just execute a `select` statement in PL/SQL without `into` and receive its resulset

Comment: @astentx : I've solved the SQL Server side of the equation. It's the Oracle half I am having issues with. The part with the "Then you need"... sounds like what I need. But are they accessible directly in SQL that JDBC can understand? Do you have a link to an example? The odd thing is I saw some Oracle/Python code using cursors but obviously that's not direct SQL either. https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#bind

Comment: Ah.. Found this..https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets .. So it depends on the outbound parameter being defined as SYS_REFCURSOR  - I don't have visibility to the Oracle stored procedures to know if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Kind of. This is SQL*Plus (command-line tool):

Procedure with an OUT parameter (just like yours):

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_deptno in dept.deptno%type,
  2                                      par_dname out dept.dname%type)
  3  as
  4  begin
  5    select dname
  6      into par_dname
  7      from dept
  8      where deptno = par_Deptno;
  9  end;
 10  /

Procedure created.
```

Declare a variable:

```
SQL> var v_dname varchar2(20);
```

Execute the procedure:

```
SQL> exec p_test(10, :v_dname);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Print** the result:

```
SQL> print v_dname

V_DNAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCOUNTING

SQL>
```

---

What if the procedure returns *many rows*? Then you could return refcursor:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_deptno in dept.deptno%type,
  2                                      par_dname out sys_refcursor)
  3  as
  4  begin
  5    open par_dname for
  6      select dname
  7      from dept
  8      where deptno <= par_deptno;
  9  end;
 10  /

Procedure created.

SQL> var v_dname refcursor
SQL>
SQL> exec p_test(40, :v_dname);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print v_dname

DNAME
--------------
ACCOUNTING
RESEARCH
SALES
OPERATIONS

SQL>
```

Comment: Huh, procedure would then return e.g. CLOB datatype and you'd then *handle* it, somehow. Or, if the procedure used UTL_FILE package, the result could have been a **file** (CSV, XML, whatever), stored in a filesystem directory and you could do something with that file.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for me I'm afraid. SQL_Plus isn't what I have to work with - just SQL that gets executed via a JDBC driver.